# Grafana+InfluxDB: show series based on value of custom variable

Tags: grafana, influxdb

Using Grafana+InfluxDB, is it possible to show a series based upon the value of a custom variable?

I tried using `AND "$variable"="value"`, ie `AND "true"="true"` but InfluxDB was interpreting it as a field and not just a boolean expression.

Comment: So what is your expected query upon interpolating the custom variable? And what is your current query.